# Is there any way to subtract two dataframes with alphanumeric datatype. I tried using except but the count of records is not coming correctly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to subtract two data frames in scala and my datatypes are alphanumeric like I have a string as the data type for id column. I tried using except

```
df1.merge(
    df2, how='outer', indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1) 

val df1 = Seq(("1","2019-04-03 14:45:00","1"),("2","2019-04-03 14:45:00","1"),("3","2019-04-03 14:45:00","1")).toDF("ID","Timestamp","RowNum") 
val df2 = Seq(("2","2019-04-03 13:45:00","2"),("3","2019-04-03 13:45:00","2")).toDF("ID","Timestamp","RowNum") 
val idDiff = df1.select("ID").except(df2.select("ID")) 
val outputDF = df1.join(idDiff, "ID")
```

But nothing helps. I was not getting the correct count. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the outputDF should contains only one record `"1","2019-04-03 14:45:00","1"` ?

I've ran your code and looks like it works, you can get same result with `left_anti` join.

```
  val idDiff = df1.select("ID").except(df2.select("ID"))
  val outputDF = df1.join(idDiff, "ID")
  outputDF.show()

  df1.join(df2,Seq("ID"),"left_anti").show()
```

```
    +---+-------------------+------+
    | ID|          Timestamp|RowNum|
    +---+-------------------+------+
    |  1|2019-04-03 14:45:00|     1|
    +---+-------------------+------+

    +---+-------------------+------+
    | ID|          Timestamp|RowNum|
    +---+-------------------+------+
    |  1|2019-04-03 14:45:00|     1|
    +---+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: It is not working that code is just an example for what all I used. I have around 37 million records in one df and another df is having around 950 records now i want to get a new df with the subtract of (37million - 950). This is the what is expected but i am not getting correct count.after using all the above examples. Kindly let me know if there is any other way possible and is there any criteria of adding the olumn you want to join with?

Comment: you can add columns in .where clause , `df1.join(df2).where(df1("ID")===df2("ID"))`, or create tempView of both dataframes and put your sql query to `spark.sql("your sql query")`